# Does Spark SQL provide an API to parse a SQL statement and corresponding DDL and infer data types of the select list?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm reviewing Spark SQL for a project and I see all the pieces of the API I need (SQL Parser, Dataset, Encoder, LogicalPlan, etc) however I'm having difficulty tying them together the way I'd like.

Essentially I want the following functionality:

```java
var ddl = parseDDL(RAW_DDL);
var query = parseQuery("SELECT c1, c2 FROM t1 WHERE c2='value'", ddl);
var selectFields = query.getSelectFields();
for(var field: selectFields) {
    var name = field.getName();
    var type = field.getType(); // <~~~ want this in terms of `t1` from ddl
    ...
}
```

The type information for the select list in terms of the DDL is what I'm after.

Ideally I'd like a soup-to-nuts example with Spark SQL, if possible.

> UPDATE
>
> To clarify let's say I have an SQL schema file with several `CREATE TABLE` statements:
>
> File: **com/abc/MovieDb.sql**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movie (
    Title varchar(255),
    Year integer,
    etc.
);
CREATE TABLE Actor (
    FirstName varchar(255),
    LastName varchar(255),
    etc.
);
etc.
```

> I want to use Spark SQL to parse a number of **arbitrary** SQL SELECT statements against this schema. Importantly, I want to get type information about the *select list* of each query in terms of the Movie, Actor, etc. tables and columns in the schema.  For example:

```sql
SELECT Title, Year FROM Movie WHERE Year > 1990
```

> I want to parse this query against the schema and get the type information for the select list.  Again the queries are arbitrary, however the schema is stable so something like:

```java
var parser = createParser(schema);
var query = parser.parseQuery(arbitraryQuery);
var selectedFields = query.getSelectedFields();
for (var field: selectedFields) {
    var name = field.getName();
    var type = field.getType();
}
```

> Most important is the `field.getType()` call.
>
> I assumed this would be an easy Yes or No type question, but perhaps my use-case is off the beaten path. Time to dive into it myself...

Comment: not sure what you are looking for here, I dont think there is DDL behind spark or spark SQL.  all you have is DAG that can show you the query execution plan behind it  if you add .explain() at the end.

Comment: By DDL I mean "schema", a way of initializing and providing context for the spark sql parser to infer types from select list fields.  But from your description it sounds like spark is not able to provide type information as I'd like.  Thanks.

Comment: when you have a dataframe  or dataset spark can either infer schema by looking at the data provided.  if you have a Dataframe you can simply write df.printSchema  or df.schema to obtain schema for all columns.  moreover, you can provide your custom schema while reading a file into dataframe

Comment: Right.  But I need to get type information from a SQL query against the the dataset/frame.  Is that possible?

Comment: yes you can just do columns.dtypes that should give you the name of the column and the datatype from the dataframe

Comment: see the answer below and let me know if you can compile that and if that is what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

to get columns information  here is what can be done 
suppose you have  dataframe with columns A,B,C,D in it

```
val  inputDf= Seq(("foo","Bar",0,0.0)).toDf("a","b","c","d")
val newDf = inputDf.select("a","c")
val columnInfo= newDf.dtypes // should give you something like (("a","StringType"),("c","IntegarType"))
```

again this is not tested code  but generally this is how you can get the column names and their types.

Comment: if you can share a working code snippet of what you already have. I Think the code snippet you have in your question is just Pseudo, correct ?